# Jenkins Timeouts using PTC Integrity on Windows Server 2012

Tags: command-line, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012, jenkins

I have installed Jenkins 2.121.3 on Windows Server 2012.

When Jenkins is communicating with the PTC Integrity server, there are timeouts.  This occurs when Jenkins runs a batch file or by using the Jenkins PTC Integrity plugin.

There are no timeouts when the same batch file is run in a command window (not as admin).  There are no timeouts when the PTC Integrity commands are issued in the command window.

Jenkins is running as a Windows service.  The service is configured to run as a user that has permission to access the PTC Integrity server.

?What is causing the timeouts when Jenkins is running?

Notes:
1. The PTC Integrity server is running when Jenkins is running.
2. The PTC Integrity server is running when the commands are issued from the Command window.
3. The PTC Integrity commands that are timing out are "si connect" and "si checkout".

Background:  We are promoting our servers from Windows Server 2008 to Windows Server 2012.

OS: Windows Server 2012
Jenkins: 2.121.3
PTC Integrity: 11.1.0.961, API Version 4.16.961.

Comment: Downvoters:  Please leave a comment as to why you downvoted the question.

Comment: Why are you complaining about downvotes when you haven't got any? In any case downvote comments are not obligatory and complaining about them is likely to result in more.